# Pivot Table filter Wrongly Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use Record Macro to filter PivotTable "PR to PO Days" field label filter between 0 and 4. When i record, it can filter correctly, only show 1, 2 & 4. But when i run the macro, it is not filter correctly, 24 which is should not show always show.
Because later i want to modify the coding the values to filter in between are variable (number key in by users at cells).

Hope anyone can get help. Thank you![image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotation marks from "0" and "4", otherwise the filter considers the values as *text* and not as *values*. In a text comparison, "24" falls between "0" and "4".

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableMacro4").PivotFields("PR to PO Days")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:=0, Value2:=4
End With
```